# recaptcha appearing in 1 and not in other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recaptcha

I am trying to add recaptcha V2 in 1 of my pages but it was not showing up.

So, for testing purposes, I added it in a common location which is used by most of my pages (Master page).

To my astonishment it started appearing on a few pages and not on many others.

Is there a known conflict between the js files of recaptcha and any other library like jquery?

I searched a lot on the internet but not able to find any solution.

PFA the screenshots of a few pages (Have also mentioned the url, will keep the recaptcha available for a few days on them)

[Link with recaptcha seen](http://uat.infochoice.com.au/investment/investment-broker/)

[image: recaptcha seen]

[Link with recaptcha not seen](http://uat.infochoice.com.au/home-loans/)

[image]

As for code, I have added just 2 code:

1. In head section:

```html
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

2. Actual div:

```html
<div class="col">
    <h2>test recaptcha : </h2>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdvpP0SAAAAAIhhaQYAKU3CJg23-CHOO_9oWgiP">
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both re-captcha's are working just fine for me. But there is an enormous timeout on both pages, making them load for a very long time. The page `home-loans` even loads a bit longer. Try to load the recaptcha using `async defer` as described at [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)

Comment: @FrankW. Thank you very much for your reply. I added `async defer` and the issue still persist although it loaded a bit fast for `investments-broker`. For `home-loans`, I had kept it open the entire night but still it did not load. Is there is a forum for `recaptcha` where i can post this issue? Also which browser did you use to check this? I used chrome and firefox

Comment: I'm using `Chrome 61.0.3163.100` and `Chrome 62.0.3202.75` both on Mac OSX 10.12.6. Both reCaptcha's are loading and working for me, without the use of adblockers like uBlock or Ghostery. Page `investments-broker` is loaded in 2.12 seconds and `home-loans` in longer than 60, which was a timeout. Yes, you could check the [Google reCaptcha forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/recaptcha) forums, I've linked it for you.